# Missing Firebase headers warnings after Xcode8/Swift 3 update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I've been getting the warnings, which you can see below after updating my app, which uses Firebase, FirebaseAuth, FirebaseData etc. to iOS10 and Swift 3. I am using CocoaPods 1.0.x with Firebase and I am using `use_frameworks!`. I am able to run my project and the app works fine but I have to get rid of those warnings. The problem seems to be with missing/misplaced public header files specifically for all of my Firebase pods. There are some open issues on GitHub but to my knowledge nothing major or very close to my problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pod deintegrate, pod clean then pod update - it may be that there is just some bad references left over from previous versions?

Comment: @IanBarber yes multiple times; I also ended up deleting all of my pods from the project because of another framework and I had the same issue after I installed them again. And it only happens with Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have managed to fix the issue. There was a problem with my Git but I am not exactly sure how it came to be. I was working on a branch when this started and after merging into my master I got the message from Xcode that I cannot switch to my master branch because I have uncommitted changes.

It turns out that those uncommitted changes were the header files from Firebase and they all had the `<Firebase Header name>.h !` markup in Xcode's `Source Control -> Commit...` menu. Discarding those changes got me up and running by switching to my master branch and now the warnings are gone. I guess updating pods on a branch can cause problems - I am guessing that Firebase got updated along the way from my various `pod install` commands. Or it could have been a Build Settings item I changed on my branch.